# request denied even with using the right header

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, access-denied, request-headers

Hi im trying to write a python script which is supposed to do stuff automatically on a website. (yes...yes im trying to write a bot that can even get me ONE ps5 so im fighting fire with fire. But im also trying to learn as im new to this stuff and dont want to download one)

So back to the topic: my test code is trying to access a url which adds a certain item to a cart. However i get the following:

**You don't have permission to access (random gibberish) on this server.**

This is my Code:

```
s = requests.session()
url = 'https://*censored*/api/cart/AddProduct?pvid=75530'
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}
r = s.post(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

My first guess is that it probably has something to do with the cookie?

Comment: Hi, yes you might need to go to the web page first to initialize the session or login. If you use the same requests session (`session = requests.session()`), then you can simulate a user by accessing the pages in sequence.

Comment: first you could use DevTools in Firefox/Chrome to see how page works, If it use cookies, if it needs javaScript. Sometimes you need something more then only correct `User-Agent`. Sometime you may need other headers. Sometimes you may have to use `session` and visit main page to get cookies. And sometimes page uses more complex security system (enve use JavaScript) and then you may not get this with requests but you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser. But you can't show real URL so we can't help you.

Comment: BTW: some pages has even function to recognize if you use Selenium and block you.

Comment: somehow it worked earlier, but now it doesnt... I dont get it